# Changed DNS server for my domain and now host displays "waiting registry domain creation ack"

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers

I changed the DNS server for my ".it" domain name which is managed by OVH. Now the DNS change operation is on hold with a `waiting registry domain creation ack` message. What does this message mean?

[image]

My `/var/lib/bind/sp1n.it.hosts` on the BIND server is :

```
$ttl 10m
@   IN  SOA 81-7-10-17.blue.kundencontroller.de. franck\.dernoncourt.gmail.com. (
            1220449000
            3h
            3m
            2w
            3h )
@   IN  NS  81-7-10-17.blue.kundencontroller.de.
@   IN  NS  puck.nether.net.
@   IN  A   81.7.10.17

mail    IN  A   81.7.10.17
www IN  A   81.7.10.17
*   IN  A   81.7.10.17
```

[Here](http://whois.domaintools.com/sp1n.it) is the current WHOIS record for my domain: it points to the former DNS server.

I have other domain names on the same DNS server, they all work OK but none is a `.it` domain like this one.

Comment: Contact OVH tech support. They should be able to help you.

Comment: Does this help? http://forum.ovh.it/showthread.php?5577-Problema-Dns-dominio-it and http://forum.ovh.it/showthread.php?6416-Cambio-DNS-modifica-non-ancora-completata It looks like this is a forum that tech support watches and answers questions on: http://forum.ovh.it/ It seems that this happens partly because the .it registrar has some restrictions. It appears that all of the right pieces of information have to line up just right or it will fail.

Comment: BTW- I just put *“waiting registry domain creation ack”* into Google and there seems to be several pages on this.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for the links. I'll look into them. I don't use OVH forum anymore as they close my forum account (and removed all my posts) because I was complaining about (other) issues. OVH is one of the the largest website hosting service in Europe so it might help other users :) I did contact OVH, I'll follow-up here if they give an interesting information. I might have simply mess up my BIND configuration somewhere but usually it's quite straightforward to set up and I'm puzzled by the error message.

Comment: Perhaps some info on what you are trying to change from and change to in your question. You can use example.com and 10.0.0.10 if that helps. That might clear things up.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If OVH is acting as your registrar, it takes a little bit of time to update nameservers with the `.it` Registry so it can then propagate to other DNS servers throughout the Internet. Some Registries are quicker than others. Seems this message is indicating they're awaiting an acknowledgment for the update. I'd give it some more time since it looks like you just did this today, and then contact support at OVH if it continues more than a day.

Comment: @dan I initiated the nameserver update a while ago. I had forgotten when but looking at the screenshot I did it 2 months ago (2014-11-22), time flies :-(

Comment: OK, in that case you'd definitely want to contact OVH's support, they may have to request the nameservers be added to the Registry's database, which can be the case with some Registries and uncommon nameservers. See [this](http://www.tucowsdomains.com/name-server-dns-changes/how-do-i-change-my-name-servers-dns/) for an example.

Comment: @dan It seems that for OVH and .it domains, the stars have to align exactly right or it will be waiting forever. I still think the expedient thing to do is contact tech support and ask whiskey tango foxtrot(?) which is exactly the same in Italian. I actually tried to translate it online. ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc I've had similar experiences with Registries for other ccTLDs that use their own database. If the nameserver doesn't have the same extension  (the OP's nameservers are `.de` and `.net`) and it's not in the Registry's database already, the registrar would then need to request it be added.

Comment: @dan That's good to know. In this case I used the same nameservers with this registrar for other domain names (e.g. francky.me, wiki4games.com) so it should be okay.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks, yes I dropped a message to the OVH support, I'll follow-up here if they give an interesting information! wtf is indeed becoming part of the lingua franca :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The issue is most likely with the `.it` _Registry_. Those other domains are have a different Registry. My guess is the first nameserver is the issue (`181-7-10-17.blue.kundencontroller.de`). The second nameserver (`puck.nether.net`) is currently being displayed in WHOIS records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the secondary DNS server `puck.nether.net` was pointing to the old server's IP (at the time of the server migration https://puck.nether.net/dns/ was unavailable and apparently I forgot about it afterward):

[image]

For what reason I did receive a warning from puck.nether.net after I contacted OVH about the issue, but I had not received any before.

> ---------- Forwarded message ----------
>  From: FreeDNS Admin  
> Date: Sun, Jan 25, 2015 at 9:30 PM 
> Subject:
>   sp1n.it transfer from 81.7.14.247 
> To: Franck Dernoncourt
>
> Error was: connection failed
>
> We have been unable to transfer sp1n.it from 81.7.14.247 for more than
>   7 days.  We have marked the domain for removal from our secondary dns
>   database.  If you have fixed this condition, please reactive the
>   domain by logging in to our maintence page at
>
> http://puck.nether.net/dns/
>
> Thanks, 
> FreeDNS team
>
> Your Maintainer ID: XXXXXXX

---

Learning outcome of the story: if the DNS change operation is on hold with a `waiting registry domain creation ack message` error message, it might mean that one of the DNS servers is pointing to the wrong BIND server IP. (meaningful error messages FTW!)